# Does a good power bar help protect computer from lightning caused power fluctuation?

Tags: power-supply

Last time when a big typhoon was trolling Hong Kong, my computer froze several time after a momentarily power fluctuation ( indicated by a flash of the lighting tube ). The computer just froze at the current screen and not responding anymore, and I would had to do hard reboot.

I couldn't afford space for a UPS. Does a power bar which claimed to protected you from power fluctuation really help?

Comment: We live at modern high level building which comes with normal lightning rod. However, I've heard that last time the whole estate had been experiencing such power shortage momentarily.

Comment: No, protects against certain amount of surge (if it has surge protection), but not power fluctuations that can cause damage also. I assume power bar means power strip? Only a good quality UPS can protect against power fluctuations.

Comment: Does the flash of the lighting tube mean lack of electricity or power surge?

Comment: "flash of the lighting tube" I don't know what that means

Answer (score 1):

A power strip will help protect you against surges of power. However, you do also have to worry about Brown Outs. This is where there is a presence of power, but it is less than normal operating standards. Too much voltage or too little voltage can damage your computer. It is best like Moab mentioned to invest in a UPS.

Comment: As I said, there is not enough space for such big device. Any other suggestion?

Comment: A normal 300-odd VA UPS is hardly that big a device. Surely you have *that* much free space in your living quarters, unless it's literally a hole in the wall?